# Copying Android database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to copy another app database using RootTools library running this command:

```
[...some code before...]
new CommandCapture(0,cp -r /data/data/com.example.appname/databases /data/data/com.example.appname/database1);
[...code to run it...]
```

The *database1* folder and its content are created. But If I delete *databases* and rename *database1* to *databases*, the app is not able to read the database anymore.

NOTE: doing a copy of the database (from *databases* to *database1*) manually using Root Explorer and then renaming it back to *databases* it **does** work.

Comment: what is the database name in the code ?

Comment: *databases* is the folder

Comment: please post your sqliteopenHelper ?

Comment: It's not my app database. This is why I'm trying to copy it launching some commands with root permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. 
The command `cp` does not automatically *chmod* files and folder, so you have to do this manually.